# How to implement "record macro"-like functionality similar to Microsoft Excel?

Tags: c++, scripting, macros

How to implement "record macro" like that in Microsoft Excel? As far as I know, I can embed a scripting interpreter(eg. javascript) and make c++ objects visible to scripts, similar to the DOM in a web browser.

My question is how do you record user actions and then generate the corresponding javascript code? In Excel we can record a macro and it will generated the appropriate VBA code.

Does someone know how to implement this feature in C++ or in other languages?

PS: Can be any language/platform -- I just want an idea of how to do it.

Comment: What language? Platform? What sort of application? Look at the memento pattern for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is have dual event handlers for each menu item / button click.

As the standard event handlers fire, your secondary macro-builder events fire.
As the macro event builders fire you record a list of actions performed
e.g.

```
ActiveDocument->Save.
ActiveDocument->SaveAs.
ActiveDocument->Print.
Find (AllDocument,"ThisText").SelectFirst
Edit.Cut
Find().SelectNext
```

You can then translate those actions into your desired scripting language.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Command Pattern](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommandPattern).  Each action in the program can be represented by a Command object.  So when you're recording a macro, you both perform the command and store it in a list.  When you want to play back the macro, you simply run through the list you created, performing every command again.

You don't necessarily even need to use distinct objects, though it will probably be easier in the long run.  As an example, Emacs has keyboard macros that simply record every keystroke, then simulates those keystrokes when you play the macro back.